# Efficiently defining a lot of class attributes in Python

Tags: python

I have been browsing Stack Overflow a lot and there are quite a few topics on this issue already. However, none of the solutions are 100% acceptable for me.

I need to define a class with 50+ attributes with default values and writing e.g. (with just three attributes as an example):

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, attribute1="default1", attribute2="default2", attribute3="default3"):

        self.attribute1 = attribute1
        self.attribute2 = attribute2
        self.attribute3 = attribute3
```

is not really what I want to do because this list then just gets too long to be readable. One way to set all attributes would be this:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, attribute1="default1", attribute2="default2", attribute3="default3"):

           for key, value in vars().items():
               setattr(self, key, value)
```

but then I get a warinng about unresolved attribute references in instances created from class `A`, which I would also like to avoid. Is there a way to set the attribute references without specifying each one separately?

Comment: Ordinary Python doesn't have warnings, so those are probably generated by your IDE. What IDE are you using? The method to disable the warning will vary between products.

Comment: Yes, you are right, of course. I am using IntelliJ, but the unresolved attribute references will also decrease the usability of the software because the attributes won't get listed for auto-completion :)

Comment: What about a dictionary like `self.dic` with attribute name as keys and values of them as as values? though they will not be attributes actually, you have access them via single attribute.

Comment: I also thought about using a dictionary, but this would not allow me to access the attribute references. Maybe this is the best way in the end, but before I change my code I wanted to make sure there is no easy way to list attribute references :) Also this decreases the usability because the dictionary entries are "less visible" then normal class attributes

Comment: You could potentially consider __slots__, have your attributes defined within slots and set their default value at class init time. If you're going to have lots of instances of this given class, slots may provide you an optimization bonus, though don't take this for granted.

Comment: *"I need to define a class with 50+ attributes with default values"* - then you likely have a broader design problem, see e.g. https://refactoring.guru/smells/long-parameter-list

Comment: You can override `__getattr__` to delegate to `self.dict` so that users can still access your attributes normally. Your IDE might even notice.

Comment: @jonrsharpe excelent point.

Comment: *"none of the solutions are 100% acceptable for me"* - please be more specific. What solutions have you seen, and what precisely is the problem with them? That way we can avoid telling you what you already know.

Comment: Using `self.__dict__[key] = value` is even worse than using `setattr()` as it totally bypasses eventual descriptors in your class or it's parents. And really, 50 attributes on a class is sure design smell so better to fix your design than to write ugly half-backed code only to satisfy your IDE.

Comment: https://refactoring.guru/smells/large-class